# How to disable opening and closing brace content assist

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to remove a default content assist from my grammar, that provides an opening and a closing brace almost everywhere.

The grammar roughly looks like:

```
Model:
    'Elements' ':' '{' elements += Element* '}'

Element:
    'Attributes' ':' '{' attributes += STRING* '}'
```

So let's say I'm writing in this grammar:

```
Attributes: { 
    "a"
    "b"
}
```

Now if I hit CTRL-Space after `"b"` it shows me a closing brace as a suggestion, but it shouldn't because a closing brace is already present.

I want to disable opening and closing brace suggestions, when they are already present in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a specialized `completeKeyword` method in your Proposal Provider (you have to find out if there is a closing `}` using information from content assist context from the node model

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate a little bit on how context can be used here, as in which functions would be relevant to use for this purpose?

Comment: there is org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.contentassist.ContentAssistContext.getCurrentNode()
org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.contentassist.ContentAssistContext.getOffset()
org.eclipse.xtext.ide.editor.contentassist.ContentAssistContext.getRootNode()
and NodeModelUtils.